# Applying custom content in Orchard (jquery slider)

Tags: html, css, orchardcms

I would like to apply a slider on my start page (nivo slider).

Slider HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="Images/Demo/walle.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="Images/Demo/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="Images/Demo/story.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently i am able to edit the content on the start page directly (enabling of the proper modules like widget content).

It is possible to insert HTML here but where exactly does all this HTML go? When i make a attempt to find the html I've added search comes back with 0 results.

- Where exactly does all the HTML go? I feel like having no control whatsoever.
- Where do i place `Style.Include("slider.css");` ? I do not want to place it on Layout.cshmtl.
- What is the proper place to include and place custom javascript files?

I would like a `.cshtml` page in the `Views` folder for every page on my website (like a MVC4 project so i have a clear overview).

When updating some text on the start page for testing  I've tried "search in files" but was unable to find anything.

Do i have to create / copy a view into my custom theme so i can exactly see where the HTML is located (if so which one, and how does this work for new pages)?

**Orchard Version:** Source version 1.6 (Visual Studio)

Thanks.

Comment: All the content you build in a cms is going into the database, not into files. You might want to use one of the modules that are doing that sort of thing rather than build your own just yet. It looks like you have a lot to learn before that and would probably be better off learning with simpler things, and start with the bases of web development and CMS.

Comment: I see, i made a wrong assumption then (new to CMS). If for example the content of page X is located in the database where to place a include (css, javascript) for that certain page? Also when i open the .SDF file with SQL server management studio i get a incompatible database version error. Thanks.

Comment: I was also wondering on how to edit html in a formatted way. I can place HTML after i have pressed the edit button. Is this normal behaviour or how can one see the HTML as like it would be on a normal html page (formatted and colored). Cheers!

Comment: You should not add Javascript or css from a page in general. This is better done in a reusable way in a module or in your theme. The Vandelay Industries module does have a feature (called Classy) that lets you add a stylesheet to a specific piece of content but you should be careful about using it or your site will become unmanageable fast.
The default HTML editor does not include the site's stylesheet while editing.